# `objc_setAssociatedObject` and `objc_getAssociatedObject` isn't match

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, crash

I just want to add a property to `UIView` like this,

```
#import "UIView+Extension.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIView (Extension)

- (void)setMaxWidth:(CGFloat)maxWidth {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(maxWidth), @(maxWidth), OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN);
}

- (CGFloat)maxWidth {
    return [objc_getAssociatedObject(self, _cmd) doubleValue];
}

@end
```

but sometime it's useful, some time is crashed.

I got the crash info in XCode is this line `return [objc_getAssociatedObject(self, _cmd) doubleValue];`.

[image]

and I got the crash in Bugly is this `NSInvalidArgumentException -[_UILabelStringContent doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2804fb280`.

[image]

So Why this happend. I just set a `float value` but get a `_UILabelStringContent value`.

PS:  My project is in swift 5.0, but I just use Objective-C runtime to add extra properties.

PS2: I used the same code in another Objective-C project, It will not crash.

PS3: It's not always crash.

PS4: I used the this property in `UIView` and `BaseLabel`, but only crash in `BaseLabel`.

PS5: I used it to update frame, I used it in `BaseLabel` like this.

```
override func sizeToFit() {
        super.sizeToFit()
        if self.maxWidth > 0 {
            if numberOfLines != 1 {
                let size = self.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: maxWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
                self.size = size
            } else {
                if self.size.width > maxWidth {
                    self.size.width = maxWidth
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

PS6: Is the crash call by `_cmd` in `objc_getAssociatedObject(self, _cmd)`??

Comment: It looks like the associated object is being released, and the memory reused for some other object.  Try enabling NSZombie debugging to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `- (void)setMaxWidth:(CGFloat)maxWidth` you are **creating** `NSNumber` backing object that holds the value for your `CGFloat` implied by `@(maxWidth)` shortened syntax. Since `NSNumber` is a subclass of `NSObject` you are not supposed to use `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN` which is not valid for types with reference counts handled by ARC (it's valid for value types like `Integer`). You should use `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN` instead.
Update your code to

```
- (void)setMaxWidth:(CGFloat)maxWidth {
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(maxWidth), @(maxWidth), OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN); 
}
```

About your PS6 part `_cmd` is the selector name (internally represented as `char*`) in a given objective-c method body. It's passed as a "hidden" argument (from obj-c syntax perspective) for each method call through a selector. Accessing it is not a likely cause of crash unless the method call is malformed somehow.